# android facebook loginbutton automatically sign in

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

i want to use facebook loginbutton but unformtuanately it is automatically signed in, i want to make it sign out automatically and user press it then the login process begins, i know it is automatically signed in because i am signed in in my android facebook application.

code/h3>

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/authButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if I understood the question correctly, you want the opposite of what MuhammadAamirALi posted. what should be something like this:

in the OnCreate method:

```
    Session activeSession = Session.getActiveSession();
    //Checks for an open session
    if (!(activeSession == null || activeSession.getState().isClosed())) {
        //if found one, kill it. 
        activeSession.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
    }
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info", "email"));
```

If anyone knows of a better way of accomplishing the same, I would like very much to know (as I'm facing this issue right now). Like, how to PREVENT Facebook from checking for a open session when the button gets created.

Comment: Is this still the best way or was something new found?

Answer (score 0):

```
In onCreate method.


        Session activeSession = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (activeSession == null || activeSession.getState().isClosed()) {
            activeSession = new Session.Builder(context).setApplicationId(context.getString(R.string.app_id)).build();
            activieSession = Session.setActiveSession(activeSession);
        }
        Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

        LoginButton login = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login);
        login.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_groups", "user_photos"));


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
    // session is not null, the session state change notification
    // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```